# Is there a way to combine two stars object containing the same variable sets at different locations in r

Tags: r, tidyverse, r-sf, r-stars

I'm trying to combine different raster data sets at different locations into one raster object. I just found the `stars` package in r that may potentially do this, and I like this package a lot because a lot of the `tidyverse` methods are compatible. However, I did not find a good function to achieve the functionalities of something like `row_bind()`. For example, if I have two separate `stars` object from two states and I want to combine them into one `stars` object. See the following example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stars)

rhode = read_stars('Data/zz/Rhode.tif') %>% 
  st_transform(crs = 4326) %>% 
  rename(ndvi = `Rhode.tif`)

delaware = read_stars('Data/zz/Delaware.tif') %>% 
  st_transform(crs = 4326) %>% 
  rename(ndvi = `Delaware.tif`)
```

Below is how the two `stars` object look:

```
> rhode 
stars object with 2 dimensions and 1 attribute
attribute(s):
          Min. 1st Qu. Median      Mean 3rd Qu.   Max. NA's
ndvi [1] 0.214 0.44665 0.4922 0.4827789  0.5251 0.7493  189
dimension(s):
  from to offset delta refsys point                      values x/y
x    1 18     NA    NA WGS 84 FALSE [18x20] -71.925,...,-71.075 [x]
y    1 20     NA    NA WGS 84 FALSE   [18x20] 41.075,...,42.025 [y]
curvilinear grid

> delaware
stars object with 2 dimensions and 1 attribute
attribute(s):
           Min. 1st Qu. Median      Mean 3rd Qu.  Max. NA's
ndvi [1] -0.128  0.3935 0.4543 0.4296167 0.48755 0.607  270
dimension(s):
  from to offset delta refsys point                      values x/y
x    1 18     NA    NA WGS 84 FALSE [18x30] -75.825,...,-74.975 [x]
y    1 30     NA    NA WGS 84 FALSE   [18x30] 38.425,...,39.875 [y]
curvilinear grid
```

Is there a straightforward function to combine these two `stars` objects into a single `stars` object?
Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Is this not it? https://r-spatial.github.io/stars/reference/c.stars.html

Comment: @TrainingPizza Simply using `c.stars` will incur an error: `c(rhode, delaware)`->
Error in c.stars(rhode, delaware) :
  don't know how to merge arrays: please specify parameter along. Specifying parameters will not incur an error, but the resulting `stars` object is wrong: `c(rhode, delaware, along = 'y')`-> stars object with 2 dimensions and 1 attribute
dimension(s):
  from to offset delta refsys point                      values x/y
x    1 18     NA    NA WGS 84 FALSE [18x20] -71.925,...,-71.075 [x]
y    1 50     NA    NA WGS 84 FALSE           42.025,...,38.425 [y]
curvilinear grid

Comment: Looks like you can only combine the objects if they have the same dimensions, which yours do not. Depending on what you're trying to do, you might be able to work with them in a list to apply the same functions

Comment: Your data seems not to be georeferenced and is floating in the WGS 84 reference system.i.e. it misses `offset` and `delta`. So you don't know where the grid is located in x, y and what the resolution of the grid deltax, deltay is. If you know it, you can set it by using `st_set_dimensions()`. After this step, If both grids have the same offset and delta you could use `st_mosaic()`. If the grids have different offset and delta you need to resample one of the objects to the other one's grid using `st_warp()`.